# NHibernate Criteria Transform Result

Tags: nhibernate

I have an SecurityGroup entity witch has Memebers and Application properties.
Application is a lookup.

So securityGroups is in many-to-many relationship with User table and one-to-many with LookupApplciation (FK)

Now I want to select all application linked to a specific user.

I have follow criteria:

```
 public IList<LookupApplication> GetApplicationByUser(User user)
    {
        return
            this.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(SecurityGroup), "sg")
            .CreateAlias("Members", "u")
            .CreateAlias("Application", "al")
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("u.Id", user.Id))

            .List<LookupApplication>();

    }
```

It trows an exception

```
The value "Edi.Advance.Core.Model.Security.SecurityGroup" is not of type "Edi.Advance.Core.Model.Lookups.LookupApplication" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
Parameter name: value
```

and it is right.

How can I transform the result to `IList<LookupApplication>?`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only return the type which you create the criteria from.

The easiest way starting from the code you have will be:

```
    return
        this.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(SecurityGroup), "sg")
        .CreateAlias("Members", "u")
        .CreateAlias("Application", "al")
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("u.Id", user.Id))
        .List<SecurityGroup>()

        // get the lookup applications in memory
        .SelectMany(x => x.LookupApplications);
```

This loads all `SecurityGroups` into memory, even if it only needs the `LookupApplication`s. This might not be an issue when you need them anyway or when they are small.

You could also reverse the query and start from the `LookupApplication`

```
    return
        this.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(LookupApplication), "la")
        // requires navigation path from SecurityGroup to LookupApplication
        .CreateCriteria("la.SecurityGroup", "sg")
        .CreateAlias("Members", "u")
        .CreateAlias("Application", "al")
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("u.Id", user.Id))
        .List<LookupApplication>()
```

Or use **HQL**, which has some features not available in Criteria, `items` gets all the items from a collection:

```
select sg.LookupApplications.items
from SecurityGroup sg inner join sg.Members u
where u.Id = :userId
```

HQL is actually recommended when you don't have dynamic queries.

**Update**, from isuruceanu's comment:

```
Session
  .CreateQuery(
      @"select sg.Application 
      from SecurityGroup sg 
          inner join sg.Members u 
      where u.Id = :userId") 
  .SetParameter("userId", user.Id)
  .List<LookupApplication>();
```

Comment: First one works fine. Second not as LookupApplication is an lookup entity and it doesn't know about securityGroups.

third one is hql :)

so first one is best one for me, as generate only one select  statement. Thanks

Comment: why HQL is recommended? I usually do not like hql, although used to write TSQL for 4 years :D

Comment: Session.CreateQuery(
                    "select sg.Application from SecurityGroup sg inner join sg.Members u where u.Id = :userId")
                    .SetParameter("userId", user.Id).List<LookupApplication>();

final query :) 

Thanks, I should review my point of view about hqls

Comment: Put this code into my answer (where it is easier to read). HQL is recommended because it is more powerful and because could be put in mapping files (named queries, it gets precompiled).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the SecurityGroup looks like and how LookupApplication looks like.

You could use ResultTransformer like:

```
.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<LookupApplication>())
.List<LookupApplication>();
```

Granted that SecurityGroup has properties matchinig LookupAppliaction, or else you have to project those properties like:

```
.SetProjection(NHibernate.Criterion.Projections.ProjectionList()    
.Add(Projections.Property("Number"), "OrderNumber")
.Add(Projections.Property("CreatedOn"), "CreatedOn")
   .Add(Projections.Property("MemeberName"), "Name"))
 .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<LookupApplication>())
 .List<LookupApplication>();
```